# Search a word in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, search

I want to input a letter and i want to return all the words that contain that letter. For example:

```
String: "I saw a frog in my garden"
input: g
output: frog, garden
```

How could make this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you are talking about regarding dictionaries (you may misunderstand them)- but I would just [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) up the word and then check if the letter was in each one, within a [list comprehension](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html).

```
>>> String = "I saw a frog in my garden"
>>> letter = 'g'
>>> [w for w in String.split() if letter in w]
['frog', 'garden']
```

That seems to be what you want.

Comment: The dictionary has the split content in it. i want to search in that dictionary what word's has the letter "g"

Comment: @Pnelson I don't understand. Could you extend your question?

Comment: I want to input a letter and i want to return all the words that contain that letter.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite useful to know which letter the list represents:

```
contains = {}
contains[letter] = [w for w in String.split() if letter in w]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have split the string as a list of words and created a dictionary using those words as keys. given that, the following function takes a dictionary and a character and returns a list of keys on that dictionary which have that character:

```
def keys_have_char(dict, char):
    return [key for key in dict.keys() if char in key]
```

Notice that I haven't added any checks, so this assumes that dict is indeed a dictionary and will work not only with single chars, but with any substrings as well.